# HTML form input type="password" CSS not working

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to add CSS to the following HTML form:

```css
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out, width 0.4s ease-in-out, background 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 18px;
  color: dimgray;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] :focus {
  animation-name: smooth;
  background-color: #FFD800;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form action="dashboard.php" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

  <br><br>
  <h2 align="center">Login</h2><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Username" name="Username"><br><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

The CSS works for `input type="text"` but not `input type="password"`. Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `php` , I've removed the tag.

Comment: Sorry, that's an extra bit of code I had copied in. Any suggestions as to my question? Thank you!

Comment: I would say you didn't arrange your code well

Comment: Can you be more descriptive for your issue. Which css is not working?

Comment: Can you consider to add Snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this now, you have un necessary space between `input[type=text], input[type=password]` and `:focus` which was the issue that focus css was not applying:

```css
  input[type=text], input[type=password]  {
        transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out, width 0.4s ease-in-out, background 0.4s ease-in-out;
        padding: 18px;
        color: dimgray;
    }
    input[type=text], input[type=password]:focus {
        animation-name: smooth;
        background-color: #FFD800;
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<form action="dashboard.php" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                    
    <br><br><h2 align="center">Login</h2><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Username" name="Username"><br><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            
</form>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tv2fwrz/)

Comment: Solved! Thank you!

Comment: Done, I've marked it as accepted! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change the User input to "text" type. Secondly, remove space between the `input[type=text], input[type=password]` and `:focus` elements over CSS.

```css
  input[type=text], input[type=password]  {
        transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out, width 0.4s ease-in-out, background 0.4s ease-in-out;
        padding: 18px;
        color: dimgray;
    }
    input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
        animation-name: smooth;
        background-color: #FFD800;
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<form action="dashboard.php" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                    
    <br><br><h2 align="center">Login</h2><br>

    <!--  change type from "password" to "text"  -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username"><br><br>                                   
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            
</form>
```

Comment: Removing the space solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Kindly tick the answer which has solved your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
input[type=text],
input[type=password]  {
    transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out, width 0.4s ease-in-out, background 0.4s ease-in-out;
    padding: 18px;
    color: dimgray;
} 

input[type=text]:focus, 
input[type=password]:focus {
    animation-name: smooth;
    background-color: #FFD800;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Using only try this doesn't help the OP... add some explanation please

Comment: just some spacing issue. not big deal